# Converting Java escape characters & emojis in a sentence with Python

Tags: python, type-conversion, emoji

For example, if I was given the following string:

```
temp = "That looks great \ud83d\udc4c Good Job!"
```

How can I convert it so that it either shows the actual emoji () or the textual meaning (OK HAND SIGN)?

Final result should like:

```
temp = "That looks great  Good Job!"
```

or

```
temp = "That looks great :OK HAND SIGN: Good Job!"
```

I have tried using the emoji library in Python but it appears to only support Python escape characters. Is there any way to convert Java escape characters to Python escape characters?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for external libraries, use the built-in `str` function [str.decode()](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/decode.html)

```
print temp.decode('unicode-escape')
```

or tell python that your string contains unicode characters by making it a string literal prepending it with [`u''`](http://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/strings.html)

```
temp = u'That looks great \ud83d\udc4c Good Job!'
```

> A prefix of "u" or "U" makes the string a Unicode string

http://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/strings.html

Comment: I have tried doing what you mentioned, but I receive an error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.

Comment: If you're on python3.x+ use `bytes(temp).decode('unicode-escape')`

Comment: in Python 3, using bytes(foo) where foo is a str, you now get TypeError: string argument without an encoding